# Limit text input to quarter decimal increments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to find a way to limit a text input to a number and quarter decimal increments. For example 0.25, .5,2.75,4.0,10.5 etc. Basically an integer 0-9 and then a decimal 0,.25,.5,.75. I have tried to base it off of

```
<script>
jQuery('.numbersOnly').keyup(function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
});
</script>
```

This limits the input to a decimal number, but can't really figure out how to limit to quarter decimal increments as illustrated above. Any ideas?

Comment: What is it supposed to do if they type a number that isn't a multiple of `.25`? If you want to type `1.25`, you have to first type `1.2`, which isn't a multiple, so you can't block it as they're typing.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. use number of decimal places to let user write a number with maximum 2 decimal places
2. use `e.KeyCode == 8` to dismiss change on backspaces
3. use blur event to put correct number if its not correct

   ```
   function decimalPlaces(num) {
      var match = (''+num).match(/(?:\.(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/);
      if (!match) { return 0; }
      return Math.max(
        0,
        // Number of digits right of decimal point.
        (match[1] ? match[1].length : 0)
        // Adjust for scientific notation.
        - (match[2] ? +match[2] : 0));
   }

   jQuery('.numbersOnly').keyup(function (e) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
        if(e.keyCode == 8 || decimalPlaces(this.value) < 2){
           return true;
        }
        else if(this.value % 1 != 0)
            this.value = (Math.round(this.value * 4) / 4).toFixed(2);

   });
   jQuery('.numbersOnly').on('blur',function () {
        if(this.value % 1 != 0)
           this.value = (Math.round(this.value * 4) / 4).toFixed(2);
   });
   ```

a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/m7parjgq/8/)

Comment: If you type `1.25` and want to change it to `1.5`, you can't, because every time you delete the `5` it puts it back.

Comment: Thank you, this is very usable for me.

Comment: Marvelous, did exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished with the `step` attribute of the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) html element without the need for any other javascript.

```
<input step="0.25" type="number"/>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryangates/ufwxLfb0/) of it working.

Comment: manual entry in possible and user will still able to put values

Comment: @user2181397 The field would still be invalid and wouldn't allow the user to submit the form. Why does it matter if the user can type an invalid value into the field?